# eaccelerator 0.9.6.1 and --with-eaccelerator-shared-memory doesn't work

Tags: php, compilation, configure, eaccelerator

I tried to compile **eaccelerator 0.9.6.1** with **--with-eaccelerator-shared-memory** flag but after:

```
./configure --with-eaccelerator-shared-memory
```

got this message:

```
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --with-eaccelerator-shared-memory
```

I need content cache enabled, so get_ and set_ functions

Answer (score 1):

The user cache functions were removed in 0.9.6 and therefore also the switch with-eaccelerator-shared-memory.

https://eaccelerator.net/wiki/Release-0.9.6

Older versions won't compile with PHP 5.3.

Answer (score 0):

Did you run phpize first to get php version? I just ran configure --with-eaccelerator-shared-memory on my box and I get this output:

> checking whether the gcc linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes

Maybe your linker doesn't support the building of shared libraries? Just check your gcc installation again (apt-get update).